# query builder select the id from leftJoin

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a select field that fetch from an entity
and I would like to customize completely my select by choosing the table the id is picked from
(here I would like to select `t.id` instead of `tl.id` as the select value)

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('tl')
    ->addSelect('l')
    ->addSelect('t')
    ->leftJoin('tl.lang', 'l')
    ->leftJoin('tl.type', 't')
    ->where('l.isDefault = 1')
    ->orderBy('tl.name', 'ASC');
```

Due to my tables, I can't simply fetch the table t, I have to use tl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not according to the syntax defined in Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html

Your query might work in Doctrine 1.2 but in Doctrine 2 you should build your query according to the syntax defined in the link I posted above.

For example `->addSelect('l')` is not being used in Doctrine 2 anymore. It has become `->add('select', 'l')`.

Comment: ->addSelect('l') is a shortcut to ->add('select', 'l')

Comment: How do you append selection fields based on some conditions. ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set different alias for your column. It'll be hydrated as column of the related entity.